# Delete instance of an object that is also stored in a list?

Tags: python, class, object, instance

I have created a class for items with a list that I can iterate over these! How can I remove instances that they do not "exist" any not appear in the list anymore?

```
class item:

    _list = []

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._list.append(self)
        self.pos = []
        self.pos.extend((x,y))

    def __str__(self):
        return "x = " + str(self.x) + " / y = " + str(self.y)

a = item(10,11)

for i in item._list:
    print(i)

# does not work:

del a
item._list.remove(a)
```

When I use `del a` the object is no more existent, but still appears in the list - even if I use `item._list.remove(a)` it still appear on iteration.

Comment: I believe he meant `del i` in the iteration. @GoodDeeds.

Comment: @UlrichBien Edit your post if you are posting code -- don't post code in the comments area.

Comment: Yes, sorry! I am new here...

Comment: What do you think `self._list.append(self)` means? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: With this I can iterate over all created instances! (see code below)

Comment: Oh, it's a class variable... I see.

Comment: If you use `del a` first, then `item._list.remove(a)` will not work anymore because you've deleted the `a` name. If you omit `del a` (or do it later), `item._list.remove(a)` works fine. But you've got different errors (`x` and `y` do not exist as attributes). Please clarify what exactly you get or what you mean by "does not work".

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do by adding `self` to a [class variable](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3#class-variables) is bad practice. You are better off doing the following (though this also isn't "perfect" practice):

```py
item_list = []

class Item:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        item_list.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "x = " + str(self.x) + " / y = " + str(self.y)

a = Item(10,11)

for i in item_list:
    print(i) # > x = 10 / y = 11

item_list.remove(a)
print(item_list) # > []
del a
```

Better practice would be to simply create a list and add items after creating them:

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return "x = " + str(self.x) + " / y = " + str(self.y)

item_list = []
items = [(10, 11)]
for x, y in items:
    item_list.append(Item(x, y))

for i in item_list:
    print(i) # > x = 10 / y = 11
```

Here is the OOP (object oriented programming) way of doing this:

```py
class Items:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def create_item(self, x, y):
        if not isinstance(x, int) and not isinstance(y, int):
            raise Exception("X and Y coordinates must be integers!")
        elif Item(x, y) in self.items:
            raise Exception("X and Y coordinates are already in the item list!")

        self.items.append(Item(x, y))

    def delete_item(self, x, y):
        if Item(x, y) not in self.items:
            raise Exception("X and Y coordinates given are not in item list!")
        else:
            self.items.remove(Item(x, y))


class Item:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __str__(self):
        return "x = " + str(self.x) + " / y = " + str(self.y)

items = Items()
items.create_item(10, 11)

print("First:")
for item in items.items:
    print(item)

items.create_item(15, 12)
items.delete_item(10, 11)

print("\nSecond:")
for item in items.items:
    print(item)
```

outputs:

```
First:
x = 10 / y = 11

Second:
x = 15 / y = 12
```